# Why do I get 500 error when I use .htaccess file

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

My website runs fine on server, but when I add following codes to .htaccess file, then it shows 500 server misconfiguration error.

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond $1 !^(index.php|resources|robots.txt) 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]

php_value upload_max_filesize 20M
php_value post_max_size 20M
php_value max_input_time 500
php_value max_execution_time 500
```

My website is created with Codeigniter. How could I get rid of this problem.

Comment: You will have to contact your hosters -- some don't allow you to change values in php.ini

Comment: Check your Apache error.log and see what error shows up there.

Comment: how could I check for Apache error.log on server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Always check whether require modules are enabled or not

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine on 
 RewriteCond $1 !^(index.php|resources|robots.txt) 
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_php5.c>
 php_value upload_max_filesize 20M
 php_value post_max_size 20M
 php_value max_input_time 500
 php_value max_execution_time 500
</IfModule>
```